# Google Workspaces (g-suite): How to filter users by email domain?

Tags: g-suite

We have a relatively large Google Workspaces account with around 50 org units, about the same number of domain names, and about 500 users.

I've been tasked with changing the email domain for all users in one particular business unit. However, some of these users were originally added to the top level org unit, not the one specific to this business unit.

This makes them problematic to find.

I haven't been able to find any way to search for users based on their domain name.

In the user admin area, the filter tool only seems to have an option to do a "Starts with" search for email addresses, and as far as I can see doesn't seem to support any kind of wildcard character. If I try to filter by "@mydomain.com", it doesn't work at all.

Is there some kind of hidden advanced search option to allow me to do what I'm trying to do.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

not sure it is usefull for you but you can download all your user info into a Google Sheet...then you can use formulas to select only the users you want.

pro-tips: when you have your user in a Sheet you can export to csv and change what you want with GAM (admin command line for Google Workspace, see here : https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM)

command for GAM is (with 2 columns "olduseraddress" and "newuseraddress")

`gam csv mylist.csv gam update user ~olduseraddress email ~newuseraddress`

Comment: Thanks @Lionel GUYOT, This is basically what I ended up doing. Except I just made the changes in the csv directly, and then re-uploaded using the "bulk update users" feature.